# Calculating the asymptotic of integrals

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, asymptotics

For an integral like
$$D_{n}(x) \equiv \int_{0}^{x} \frac{t^{n}}{e^{t}-1} d t$$
The asymptotic values are given as

$$D_{n}(x) \simeq\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
n ! \zeta(n+1)-x^{n} e^{-x}+O\left(x^{n} e^{-2 x}\right), & x \rightarrow \infty \\
x^{n} / n-x^{n+1} / 2(n+1)+O\left(x^{n+2}\right), & x \rightarrow 0
\end{array}\right.$$

For $x\to 0 $, I can just Taylor expand $\frac{1}{e^t-1}$ as $\frac{1}{t}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{t}{12}-\frac{t^3}{720}+O\left(t^5\right)$ and do term by term integration to to get the given expression.

For $x\to \infty $ the first term is simply gotten by replacing the upper bound of the integral with $\infty$ but how are the correction terms calculated?

Comment: Expand $\frac{1}{e^t-1} = e^{-t}\cdot \frac{1}{1 - e^{-t}}$ in a geometric series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The asymptotics you gave is not completely correct. I am going to derive the correct asymptotic form. First, we write
\begin{align*}
D_n (x) & = n!\zeta (n + 1) - \int_x^{ + \infty }  \frac{{t^n }}{{e^t  - 1}}dt 
 \\ & \mathop  = \limits^{t = x(1 + s)} n!\zeta (n + 1) - x^{n + 1} e^{ - x}  \int_0^{ + \infty }  e^{ - xs} \frac{(1 + s)^n }{1 - e^{ - x(1 + s)}}ds .
\end{align*}
Now, by the geometric series,
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} \frac{{(1 + s)^n }}{{1 - e^{ - x(1 + s)} }}ds}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} (1 + s)^n ds}  + \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} (1 + s)^n \mathcal{O}(e^{ - x(1 + s)} )ds} .
$$
By Watson's lemma,
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} (1 + s)^n ds}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} (1 + s)^n ds}  = \frac{1}{x} + \mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{1}{{x^2 }}} \right)
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - xs} (1 + s)^n \mathcal{O}(e^{ - x(1 + s)} )ds}  = \mathcal{O}(1)e^{ - x} \int_0^{ + \infty } {e^{ - 2xs} (1 + s)^n ds}  = \mathcal{O}\left( {\frac{{e^{ - x} }}{x}} \right).
$$
Thus,
\begin{align*}
D_n (x) & = n!\zeta (n + 1) - x^n e^{ - x}  + \mathcal{O}(x^{n - 1} e^{ - x} ) + \mathcal{O}(x^n e^{ - 2x} ) \\ & = n!\zeta (n + 1) - x^n e^{ - x}  + \mathcal{O}(x^{n - 1} e^{ - x} ).
\end{align*}
**Addendum.** It can be shown that for any positive integer $n$,
$$
D_n (x) = n!\zeta (n + 1) - n!x^n \sum\limits_{j = 0}^n {\frac{1}{{(n - j)!}}\frac{1}{x^j}\operatorname{Li}_{j + 1} (e^{ - x} )} 
$$
where $\operatorname{Li}_s$ is the polylogarithm.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure, but it seems useful to make the substitution $xu = t$:
\begin{align}
D_n(x) & = \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n+1} u^n}{e^{xu} - 1} \ du \\
& = x^{n+1} \int_0^1 e^{-xu} \frac{u^n}{1 - e^{-xu}} \ du \\
& = x^{n+1} \int_0^1 e^{-xu} u^n \sum_{m=0}^\infty e^{-m x u} \ du \\
& = x^{n+1} \sum_{m=1}^\infty \int_0^1 u^n e^{-xu m} \ du. \\
\end{align}
The first term $\Gamma(n+1) - \Gamma(n+1,x)$ can be written in terms of asymptotic formulae well known for the Gamma function. Though this expansion seems to do better than the first two terms you have there...

Answer (score -1):

As Daniel mentioned, using the fact that:
$$\frac{1}{e^t-1}=e^{-t}\frac 1{1-e^{-t}}=e^{-t}\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nt}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-(n+1)t}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-nt}$$
and so:
$$D_n(x)=\int_0^x\sum_{k=1}^\infty t^ne^{-kt}dt=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\int_0^xt^ne^{-kt}dt=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\gamma(n+1,kx)}{k^{n+1}}$$
where $\gamma$ denotes the lower incomplete gamma function, so our series would be:
$$D_n(x)\approx\gamma(n+1,x)+\frac{\gamma(n+1,2x)}{2^{n+1}}+...$$